# Display function types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Other than loading a Haskell file into GHCi and then using `:type <expr>`, is there any way to have the compiler display types for all of the functions as they are compiled?

Comment: You might want to take a look [hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools) and see if you can find an integration plugin to your favourite code editor. In vim I can display the type of any expression under the cursor as I'm editing, without recompiling anything!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you pass [`-fwarn-missing-signatures`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) (or `-Wall`) to GHC it will list every top-level function that has no type annotation in the file, together with the inferred type.